# Constructor undefined while the constructor is indeed defined

Tags: java

This line causes error "The constructor Vector(double[], double[]) is undefined":

```
Vector<trainingSet> set = new Vector<trainingSet>({1.0, 1.0}, {0.0, 0.0});
```

While the class "trainingSet" has indeed a corresponding constructor:

```
public class trainingSet {
    public double [] pattern, result;
    public trainingSet(){}
    public trainingSet(double[] Pattern, double[] Result){
        pattern = Pattern;
        result = Result;
    }
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: FWIW, the **overwhelming** convention in Java code is to use initial capitals on class and interface names (so, `TrainingSet`, not `trainingSet`). You can flout that convention if you like, but it *will* result in people having trouble reading your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling constructor of Vector class which is not exist, try this,

```
    double[] Pattern={1.0, 1.0};
    double[] Result={0.0, 0.0};

    Vector<trainingSet> set = new Vector<trainingSet>();
    set.add(new trainingSet(Pattern, Result));
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you are not initializing `trainingSet` but the `Vector` class itself. `Vector` has only default constructor, constructor with initial size and you can also pass other collections to it. You should do something like

```
Vector<trainingSet> vector = new Vector<trainingSet>();
double[] result = {1.0, 1.0};
double[] pattern = {0.0, 0.0};
vector.add(new trainingSet(result, pattern));
```

Also consider using [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html) instead of `Vector` unless you don't need synchronization. `Vector` is much more slower collection then a `List`.

Comment: This line:
vector.add(new trainingSet({1.0, 1.0}, {0.0, 0.0}));
still causes an error: "The constructor HelloWorld.trainingSet(double, double, double) is undefined". That's really insane because there're obviously only 2 double[]s.

Comment: I see it has been already solved in previous answers, I will update mine too.

Answer (score 2):

Java's `Vector` has no constuctor taking a single element of the collection type. Also you are trying to construct the vector by passing two `Arrays` with doubles, not a trainingSet. Possible fix would be:

```
Vector<trainingSet> set = new Vector<trainingSet>();
set.add(new trainingSet(new double[]{1.0, 1.0}, new double{0.0, 0.0}));
```

Comment: It won't work, somehow I can't fetch any double[] directly to the constructor.
So this works:
    trainingSet s2 = new trainingSet(new double[] {1.0}, new double[]{1.1});
And this doesn't:
    trainingSet s2 = new trainingSet({1.0}, {1.1});

Comment: @crazyfffan true. I did not notice that, sorry. I don't think you can construct double array like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing parameter to vector constructor and not in the cunstructor of class named **trainingSet**

Answer (score 0):

because of your definition `Vector<trainingSet>`

Vector expects `trainingSet` type only and not `double` premitive

you can change it to

```
Vector<trainingSet> set = 

new Vector<trainingSet>().add(new trainingSet({1.0, 1.0},{0.0,0.0})));
```

Comment: does Vector have such constructor? I did not find it in the documentation.